# Implementing simple Socket programming with string compression

Tags: java

So I was trying to do some simple socket programming with string compression for our online school activity. My problem is that whenever I run the `itClient.java` the only thing that is displaying is the first character of the string, what I was expecting is that it would show or display the characters of the inputted string with the numbers indicating how many times that character occurred.

Here is the Client code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class itClient {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws UnknownHostException,IOException
    {
        Socket sckt = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 729);
            String input,temp,temp1;
            Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner scn2 = new Scanner(sckt.getInputStream());
            Scanner scn3 = new Scanner(sckt.getInputStream());

            System.out.println("Enter a String : ");
            input = scn.nextLine();

            PrintStream prnt = new PrintStream(sckt.getOutputStream());
            prnt.println(input);
                temp = scn2.next();
                temp1 = scn3.next();
                System.out.print("Compressed/Formatted Data : ");
                    System.out.print(temp);
                    System.out.print(temp1);
               
    }
}
```

Then this is the Server Code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class itServer {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        String input;
        char temp2;
        int temp1;
        int count1,count2,count3;

        ServerSocket ser1= new ServerSocket(729);
        Socket ss = ser1.accept();
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());
        PrintStream out2 = new PrintStream(ss.getOutputStream());

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(ss.getInputStream());
            input = scn.nextLine();
            count3 = input.length();

            for(count1=0; count1<count3;count1++) {
                count2 = 0;
                temp2 = input.charAt(count1+1);
                out2.println(temp2);
                while (input.charAt(count1) == input.charAt(count1 + 1))
                {
                    count2++;
                    count1++;
                }
                temp1 = count2+1;
                out.println("^" + temp1 + ",");
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to do some debugging to work out what is happening. You could step through your code using an IDE debugger, or a very easy was is to simply print useful information to the console throughout your code while testing, for example: `System,out.println("The code reached here, and the value of ??? was " + yourVariable);`

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but my guess would be the two OutputStreams on the server and InputStreams on the client. As far as I see from the code, they will just be wrappers around the same stream. So what I could think is, that the value you expect would be hiden in the next call to "scn2/3.next()". Maybe have a look into that.  Unfortunately right now I have no time to verify it myself.

Comment: Okay, I'll check on it. Thanks

Comment: I tried making this part :

```System.out.print("Compressed/Formatted Data : ");
                    System.out.print(temp);
                    System.out.print(temp1);```
Into something like this:
```System.out.print("Compressed/Formatted Data : ");
                    System.out.print(temp);
                    System.out.print("temp1");
```

From the result of x^3, it turned into xtemp1 So I'm guessing that the error is in the ```server.java```